# Piping the results of a stored procedure to .NET text box

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I have a `Winform` that simply contains a `textbox` object, which I'm trying to use as a repository for the results of a `T-SQL` stored procedure. Here is the code I'm using to connect to the database and run the stored procedure.

The SP seems to be running correctly, however it's not returning the information to the `textbox` in the way I'm expecting. It's not updating the `text` property at all.

```
Public Function ConnectToSQL() As String
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=" & Utilnamespace.SQLSvr & ";Database=Master" & ";integrated security=SSPI;")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("sp_whoisactive", con)
        con.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            txtSQL.Text = String.Format("{0}", _
               reader(0))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server. " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
    Return "Done"
End Function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you be concatenating?

```
    While reader.Read()
        txtSQL.Text += String.Format("{0}", _
           reader(0))
    End While
```